# Parse Json file in react "Error string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string"

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm doing a job to get json data on React And I need to add a download data button
Here is my data fetch function but i am getting data parsing error.
Yes if delete parse json i get data type of string but me need date type object

Please help me. This is my second day in React.

```js
const [file, setFile] = useState();
const fileRef = useRef;
const onChangeFile = async(e: React.ChangeEvent < HTMLInputElement > ) => {
  if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
    console.log(typeof e.target.files[0]);
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      console.log(typeof e.target);
      console.log(e.target);
      console.log(fileReader.result);
      console.log(typeof fileReader.result);
      let userObj = JSON.parse(fileReader.result);
      console.log(userObj);
      console.log(typeof userObj);

      // const target = e.target;
      // const result = target?.result;

      //   // setData(initialData2);
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
  }
};

return (
  <Fragment>
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
       <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
       <h1 className='App-title'>Welcome to JSON Forms with React</h1>
        <p className='App-intro'>More Forms. Less Code.</p>
     </header>
   </div>
   <input type='file' id='input_json' ref={fileRef} onChange={onChangeFile} />
  </Fragment>
)
```

```
Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345

    112 |         console.log(fileReader.result);
    113 |         console.log(typeof fileReader.result);
  > 114 |         let userObj = JSON.parse(fileReader.result);
        |                                  ^
    115 |         console.log(fileReader.result);
    116 |         console.log(typeof fileReader.result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a type check should do the job

```
let userObj = typeof(fileReader.result) == 'string' ? JSON.parse(fileReader.result) : {};
```

Comment: Very thanks. I’ve been trying to do this for two days.